# Drag coefficient of a hemisphere

Tags: aerodynamics, drag

I am looking for the aerodynamic drag coefficient of a hemisphere that is set up to flow as follows:

[image]

In the literature, I only found coefficients for the hemisphere placed in a different setting. Reynolds number is equal to $7 \cdot 10^6$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is more of a pure physics question than an aviation one. yes we deal with aerodynamics, but applied to aircraft, not idealized geometrical shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this question has been sitting out there for ages. I don't have the answer. But I do know that extensive research has been done on this topic. Here is a paper on the topic produced by Stanislav Gordeyev and Eric Jumper out of the Department of Aerospace and Mechanical Engineering, University of Notre Dame. I hope it is insightful:

[https://www3.nd.edu/~sgordeye/ReviewTurretsFinal.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Esgordeye/ReviewTurretsFinal.pdf)